# ASIO ip::tcp::iostream and TCP_NODELAY

Tags: c++, boost-asio

How do i set TCP_NODELAY option if i use ip::tcp::iostream? I need a socket for this, but i can't find how to extract it from iostream.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use [iostream::rdbuf()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket_iostream/rdbuf.html)

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

int
main()
{
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream stream;
    const boost::asio::ip::tcp::no_delay option( true );
    stream.rdbuf()->set_option( option );
}
```