# iostream and No_delay option

Tags: tcp, boost-asio

I am trying to disable the Nagle Algorithm using the answer for the same question: [ASIO ip::tcp::iostream and TCP_NODELAY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706641/asio-iptcpiostream-and-tcp-nodelay):

```
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream socketStream;
    const boost::asio::ip::tcp::no_delay option( true );
    socketStream.rdbuf()->set_option( option );
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    tcp::endpoint endpoint (tcp::v4 (), 6666);
    tcp::acceptor acceptor (io_service, endpoint);

    std::cout << "Waiting for connection.." << std::endl;
    acceptor.accept (*socketStream.rdbuf ());
    std::cout << "Connected!" << std::endl;
```

and when running the code this error appears:

```
set_option: Bad file descriptor
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you set the option, the stream is still invalid (not open).

Wait until the socket is open, before setting the option:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/896f7d2c5103357a)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

static boost::asio::ip::tcp::no_delay const no_delay_option (true);

int main() {
    using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

    tcp::iostream socketStream;


    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    tcp::endpoint endpoint (tcp::v4(), 6666);
    tcp::acceptor acceptor (io_service, endpoint);

    std::cout << "Waiting for connection.." << std::endl;
    acceptor.accept (*socketStream.rdbuf ());
    socketStream.rdbuf()->set_option(no_delay_option);

    std::cout << "Connected!" << std::endl;
    std::cout << socketStream.rdbuf() << "\n";
}
```

(We send `main.cpp` to port 6666 using netcat there)