# boost::asio::read in TCP client app takes long time to return if connectivity is lost

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio, tcpclient

I have tried to search this a lot. I am new to `network+tcp-sockets` programming.

I am using **`TCP sockets`** to communicate data over network. I have a **`host app`** & a **`client app`** both written in **`C++`** & using **`boost::asio`** on both ends to communicate data.

In the `client app`, I am using `boost::asio::read` to read some data from a `socket` in my C++ client application. The host application runs on a different machine.

Following is the code where I read some data & try to determine if there are errors.

```
boost::system::error_code error_code;
std::size_t data_received = boost::asio::read(socket, boost::asio::buffer(&data_to_read, sizeof(data_to_read)), error_code);
if (error_code == boost::asio::error::eof) {
  //ends here if the host app closes the socket
  //log error & return
}

if (data_received <= 0) {
  //log error & return
}
```

I receive a `boost::asio::error::eof` when host app closes the socket and it works to update my UI to show that I have lost the connection.

But here is the problem: When the `network/wifi` goes off on the host app then `boost::asio::read` takes a long time to return. Something like 2 minutes. Then I get a `boost::asio::error::eof` error after a long delay. Strange ! I cannot afford this latency as I need to quickly update `UI` for user that data could not be fetched from the `host app`.

***Why doesn't `asio` return quickly when network is turned off or connectivity is down ? Is there some other way to detect this or handle this ?***

*PS:* Note that `boost::asio::read` is a blocking call but it does not lock my UI thread if it takes time to return because I am doing this in a `worker thread`.

Comment: What is local IP? Because if that's loopback then it has nothing to do with wifi. Loopback "always" works

Comment: yes @sehe. But, the local IP thing was unnecessary extra info. Hence, I removed it from my question

Comment: Since you're not blocking the UI thread, why not have the UI thread update the UI and let the user know that data could not be fetched from the host? It's your choice what to do while this blocking read is blocking. If you don't want to block this thread until it is possible to complete the read or definitively fail, don't make a blocking read call. You are getting what you asked for -- if you don't like it, ask for something else.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I have read a lot about this & found the synchronous read call is faster than async_read. It works very nicely for me. Only pending problem is this one that I have asked here. I thought there would be some way to make the call fail fast.

Comment: @SegmentationFault What do you mean by "faster" exactly? Do you want the call to fail before the underlying read fails? The underlying read takes some time to fail -- in fact, it's not guaranteed to *ever* fail due to a loss of connection. (The only reliable way to detect loss of connection is to send something and see what, if anything, you get back.)

Answer (score 2):

TCP is designed to be "reliable," even in the face of seemingly catastrophic problems. It does this with a series of timers and retransmissions when the other end of a connection does not respond. How often, and how long, the retransmissions take place depends on the OS. It can be minutes, or even hours, before a connection is reported down.

Internally sockets have a group of options to control keep alive settings that you can set on the socket (if boost::asio exposes them). A quick google search for 'tcp keepalive' brought up a bunch of examples.

Another option is to implement your own timing mechanism where you constantly send packets & responses over the tcp connection & define yourself what the appropriate timing should be.

Comment: I searched for `tcp::no_delay`. Found few links like one [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706641/asio-iptcpiostream-and-tcp-nodelay). `boost::asio` seem to have support for it as well. But it seems like I can use it when using `boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream` to read my buffer. In my code if I try to set `tcp::no_delay(true)`, then should I set it before every `boost::asio::read` call ?

Comment: @SegmentationFault `tcp::no_delay` is solving a different problem. TCP keepalive is a ping that reports failures more quickly. If you have control of the protocol the best approach is to implement your own connection test mechanism as @evan describes.

Comment: I should also mention, that the keep-alive settings are platform dependent, as is their configurability.

Comment: @janm @evan thanks for your clarifications. I am trying to search some code samples & figure out how to use `TCP keepalive` to fix my situation here